# How to calculate a rotating (and constantly decelerating) wheel's angle and speed at a given time in the future?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

So imagine a wheel (a bicycle's wheel) that's spinning slower and slower (because the bike brakes). The time it takes for the wheel to complete one revolution increases in a linear way. Say it starts off with 1 second / revolution, and it increases by 0.1s every revolution (so we know that the next revolution will take 1.1s etc.). There's a marking on the wheel, so we can keep track of its orientation. Let's say that the wheel is at 0 degrees right now.

How can I calculate the wheel's angle and speed at a given point in the future, say 5 seconds from now?

Of course, I could just calculate all the revolutions until I get there, but is there an easier way?

The example is not realistic of course, but I just came up with these numbers for simplicity.

Comment: You could use angular acceleration - although it would be inverted (i.e. in seconds per radian, rather than in radians per second).

Answer (score 1):

Since the wheel has a constant angular deceleration you can derive equations of constant angular acceleration in a similar way to the equations of constant linear accleration that are much more common. I am going to cheat and just refer you to a website which has them listed but i think these are what you are looking for
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/rotq.html
(Third box)
Then given initial conditions you would be able to calculate the angle the wheel has rotated through or the angular velocity of the wheel at a given time t after t=0.